# JVM OutOfMemoryError when using -Xss2G

Tags: java, linux, jvm

I have a problem where when I try to start a program on linux with a 2G stack size, the JVM quits almost immediately with an out of memory error.

This runs with no problems

```
-Xmx8G -Xss2047m
```

These flags immediately cause the jvm to exit with an out of memory exception

```
-Xmx8G -Xss2048m
```

The box has 32GB of memory and pretty much nothing else running so I'm certain I'm not actually running out of available memory. I assume there is some kind of system limit in place, but I'm struggling to find out what it actually is.

I'm running RHEL 7.4 and using OpenJDK 1.8.0_151

Output of 'ulimit -a':

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited 
scheduling priority             (-e) 0 
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited 
pending signals                 (-i) 127929 
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64 
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited 
open files                      (-n) 1024 
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8 
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200 
real-time priority              (-r) 0 
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192 
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited 
max user processes              (-u) 8192 
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited 
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Any ideas on what I should tweak to get it to run with the full 2GB or higher?

Comment: How many threads do you have?

Comment: It's just a wrapper that launches a single threaded native process. Pretty small number of threads.

Comment: -Xss is **per-thread**, applicable to the background threads started by the JVM itself as well. Why would you need a 2G stack if it's wrapping a native process anyway?

Comment: How many? Run a JFR - count them. Now work out what this is times 2G each for Stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a JVM bug. When `ThreadStackSize` is rounded to multiple of 1K, the value is converted to `int`, see [arguments.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/a9b412abe617/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp#l2920):

```
  // Internally track ThreadStackSize in units of 1024 bytes.
  FLAG_SET_CMDLINE(intx, ThreadStackSize,
                          round_to((int)long_ThreadStackSize, K) / K);
```

So, 2G overflows to negative, and a later call to `pthread_create` fails.

The bug [JDK-8178491](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178491) is fixed in JDK 10.

It's hard to imagine a real case when such a large stack is ever needed. However, if you seriously want to create a thread with more than 2GB stack, you may use a [Thread constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread-java.lang.ThreadGroup-java.lang.Runnable-java.lang.String-long-) that accepts `stackSize` as an argument:

```
    public Thread(ThreadGroup group,
                  Runnable target,
                  String name,
                  long stackSize)
```

Comment: I guess, it’s the OP’s way to deal with the fact that the amount of stack needed for a particular Java code is entirely unspecified and unpredictable, so when a developer notices that a certain size turns out to be sometimes insufficient, so the only solution is to throw significantly more memory at it. It’s such an anachronism to have manually configured fixed stack sizes in a Java VM, especially with the size being specified in meaningless amounts of bytes…